# Merge Two lists of Tuples by common element in scala

Tags: scala, list

I have two lists of the form

`[(a,b,c,d,e,f),(h,i,j,k,l,m)]`

`[(c, d, 1), (k,l,2)]`

How can I merge both lists so that the final one is

`[(a,b,c,d,e,f,1),(h,i,j,k,l,m,2)]`

The idea is to merge on a common element in both lists

Comment: what if one item in one list matched two items or more in the other - should it be "merged" into all matching items?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your question?

Comment: @TzachZohar yeah they should be merged I don't have much experience with Scala but I was thinking of something similar to python pandas merge function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to play with data structures here. A set cannot have duplicate elements so you can easily solve this problem with a set.

```
val list1 = (List("a","b","c","d","e","f"),List("h","i","j","k","l","m"))
val list2 = (List("c", "d", 1), List("k","l",2))'
val result = (list1._1.toSet ++ list2._1.toSet, list1._2.toSet ++ list2._2.toSet)
```

If you want them as a sequence of objects then:

```
(result._1.toSeq, result._2.toSeq)
```

If you want them ordered, then you'll need to define an order function since you have Strings and Ints mixed

Comment: OP asked for merging on basis of common elements, where are you considering that??